# Pycharm debugging displays variable not available even when a breakpoint is set

Tags: python, pycharm

I am very new to python programming and debugging in `pycharm`. I want to find the value of a particular variable inside a `if` condition and have set a `breakpoint` , however the debugger shows that the variables are not available. Below is the screenshot of the code and the debugger:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're code isn't running yet. The `print(...)` line is *inside* the function, instead of *outside* the function. Your code can only run if something outside a function does something.

**Fix:** Just remove the `tab` in front of the print statement. Like so:

```
def factor(n):
    # Your function body ...
    for (...)
        # Somewhere here is the return statement

print(factor(25))  # See the start of this `print` is inline with the `def`
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and I fixed it by going through following steps :-

On the bottom left corner of your pycharm IDE, you will a settings option, click there and then go to  "variable loading policy" and set this option to "on demand".

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The OP probably didn't need this answer, but it did help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to:

1. "Run" menu,
2. "Edit Configurations",
3. In "Run/Debug Configurations" window, find the script under the "Python" section,
4. "Working directory", set it to the project root level.